# Is "Person" is reserve word on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a new model named "Person" but it returns created "people" table on database I've tried multiple times to generate and destroy I even change the migration file to create table name "persons" instead of "people" including the file name but when I have tried to create or get data it says:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'database-name_development.people' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `people`
```

Here's a sample of generate:

```
rails g model Person
Running via Spring preloader in process 17268
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20190517080311_create_people.rb
      create    app/models/person.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/person_spec.rb
```

File: 20190517080311_create_people.rb

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In Rails, the table name is the plural of the model name. *People* is the plural of *person*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to Rails' [inflections framework](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html). It has a built-in mapping from [person to people](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers/inflections.rb.tt).

You should be able to override it with the following, which you can put in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` (or any other name in that folder):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'person', 'persons'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails it default uses plural name as table name for any model. If you want to use some different name in model you can set the table name

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "persons"
end
```